# HAProxy: omiting auth for URI not working

Tags: haproxy

I need to be able to omit authentication for a specific URI using `haproxy` but using the following config file is not working. When accessing **`whatever.server/app/my-app`**, I still get asked to provide login credentials.

```
global
    maxconn 4096
    daemon

userlist myUsers
    user someUser insecure-password somePass

defaults
    mode http
    log 127.0.0.1 local1 debug
    option httplog

frontend all
    bind  0.0.0.0:80
    timeout client 86400000
    default_backend www_backend
    acl is_websocket hdr(Upgrade) -i WebSocket
    acl is_webapp path_beg /app
    acl is_my_app path_beg /app/my-app
    acl auth_ok http_auth(myUsers)
    http-request auth unless auth_ok or is_websocket or is_my_app
    use_backend webapp_backend if is_webapp

backend www_backend
    balance roundrobin
    option forwardfor # This sets X-Forwarded-For
    option httpclose
    timeout server 1800000
    timeout connect 4000
    server server1 localhost:81 weight 1 maxconn 1024 check

backend webapp_backend
    balance roundrobin
    option forwardfor # This sets X-Forwarded-For
    option httpclose
    timeout server 1800000
    timeout connect 4000
    server server1 localhost:8800 weight 1 maxconn 1024 check
```

I'm using `haproxy` v1.4

**EDIT**

Also tried

```
http-request allow if is_my_app
http-request auth unless auth_ok or is_websocket
```

but it's allowing all URLs without authentication

Answer (score 0):

Acls can be negated as mentioned here https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#7.2

```
acl url_static path_beg /app/my-app
acl AuthOkay_Web http_auth(myUsers)
http-request auth realm AuthYourself if !isOptions !url_static !AuthOkay_Web
```

Also explained at https://serverfault.com/a/874742/297275

Comment: I'm using version 1.4

Comment: it is possible in 1.4 version also.
<https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.4/configuration.html#7.7>

Comment: I have updated my answer with your variables. That should work if URI is correct. In this we are simpley creating a static url acl for the URI and then when auth is done, making it skip auth for that static url.

Comment: It would be wise to re-write your answer in order to match version1.4 (links and code)

Comment: Could you point out what's wrong with my config? I don't understand why I have to negate acls since I'm using `unless`

Comment: This should work:
`http-request auth if auth_ok or is_websocket`

As per this, if either one of ACL return **True**, condition will be True.
I hope this is same as what you want. If you want.

In case of unless, 
_the condition is TRUE if the result of the ACLs is FALSE_

Refer this ::
[https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/aloha/10-0/traffic-management/lb-layer7/writing-conditions/]